# How can I define a default list of the same length of another list

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I need help with something small. In the code bellow I've created a new object called `PersonCheck` and in it there is a list that I Moved over from another object also called `personCheck`. The thing is I want to make a list of bool which is the same length as `personCheck` I moved over in order that the index of the bool will be the same as that person.
In the code below I'm making a list of people and every person has a checkbox which will tell if he is here or not.
The thing is I need to default the list as false.
I've tried something like this but it return me this error:

> Only static members can be accessed in initializers.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PersonCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> peopleCheck;

  PersonCheck({Key key, this.peopleCheck}) : super(key: key);
  //PersonCheck(this.peopleCheck);

  @override
  _PersonCheckState createState() => _PersonCheckState();
}

class _PersonCheckState extends State<PersonCheck> {
  List<bool> chk1 = List.filled(widget.peopleCheck.length, false);
  //bool chk1=false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'People Now',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: this.widget.peopleCheck.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, value) {
          return Card(
            color: Colors.amberAccent[200],
            elevation: 3,
            child: Container(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Text(value.toString()),
                title: Text(
                  widget.peopleCheck[value],
                ),
                trailing: Checkbox(
                  value: chk1[value],
                  onChanged: (bool val) => setState(() => chk1[value] = val),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The problem is clear:**

You are trying to use a non static member in an static constructor. So this code: `List<bool> chk1 = List.filled(widget.peopleCheck.length, false);` will be executed before the `_PersonCheckState` constructor is executed and the `widget` property should only be used after that, that is why you can't use `widget` there.

You can simply fill the list `chk1` in the `initState()` there you are able to use the `widget` property.

In the code bellow I initialised the list in the `initState()` so you are good to go.

```dart
class PersonCheck extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String> peopleCheck;

  PersonCheck({Key key, this.peopleCheck}) : 
        assert(peopleCheck != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  _PersonCheckState createState() => _PersonCheckState();
}

class _PersonCheckState extends State<PersonCheck> {
  List<bool> chk1;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    chk1 = List<bool>.filled(widget.peopleCheck.length, false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text(
          'People Now',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: this.widget.peopleCheck.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, value) {
          return Card(
            color: Colors.amberAccent[200],
            elevation: 3,
            child: Container(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: Text(value.toString()),
                title: Text(
                  widget.peopleCheck[value],
                ),
                trailing: Checkbox(
                  value: chk1[value],
                  onChanged: (bool val) => setState(() => chk1[value] = val),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```